# IE8/9 $.get and .html() return data not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following JavaScript,

```
$(".refresh").on("click touch", function () {
    $.get($("a.suggest-date").attr('href') + '#suggestedDate', null, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $("#ajax-loaded").html(result)
    });
    return false;
});
```

The $.get gets the response of,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="">
    <head>
        <title>Suggest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="suggestedDate">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var map;
                        var places;
                        var iw;
                        var markers = [];

                        function initialize() {
                            var options = {
                                zoom: 15,
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.45390,-0.12246),
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                streetViewControl: false
                            };
                            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
                            map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, options);

                            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.45390,-0.12246);
                            markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatlng,
                                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker.png'
                            });
                            google.maps.event.addListener( markers[0], 'click', '');
                            dropMarker(markers[0], 0 * 100);
                    //addResult(results[i], i);
                        }

              function clearMarkers() {
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                  if (markers[i]) {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                    delete markers[i]

                  }
                }
              }

              function dropMarker(marker, delay) {
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                  marker.setMap(map);
                }, delay);
              }

              function addResult(result, i) {
                var results = document.getElementById('results');
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr.style.backgroundColor = i % 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF';
                tr.onclick = function() {
                  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
                };

                var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
                var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
                var icon = document.createElement('img');
                icon.src = result.icon;
                icon.className = 'placeIcon';
                var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
                iconTd.appendChild(icon);
                nameTd.appendChild(name);
                tr.appendChild(iconTd);
                tr.appendChild(nameTd);
                results.appendChild(tr);
              }

              function clearResults() { 
                var results = document.getElementById('results');
                while (results.childNodes[0]) {
                  results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
                }
              }

              function getDetails(result, i) {
                return function() {
                  places.getDetails({
                    reference: result.reference
                  }, showInfoWindow(i));
                }
              }

              function showInfoWindow(i) {
                return function(place, status) {
                  if (iw) {
                    iw.close();
                    iw = null;
                  }

                  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: getIWContent(place)
                    });
                    iw.open(map, markers[i]);
                  }
                }
              }

              function getIWContent(place) {
                var content = '<table style="border:0"><tr><td style="border:0;">';
                //content += '<img class="placeIcon" src="' + place.icon + '"></td>';
                content += '<td style="border:0;"><b>';
                content += 'PLACE NAME' + '</a></b>';
                content += '</td></tr></table>';
                return content;
              }



        //show_place();
        </script>
                    <div class="date-wrapper">
            <header>
            <h3>Suggest A Date</h3>
            <a href="#" class="close-date">
                <img src="http://dev64238.loveflutter.com/assets/img/close-suggest-date.jpg" alt="close" />
            </a>
            </header>
            <div class="date-details">
                <strong> Windmill Brixton</strong><br />
                 22 Bleinheim Gdns.,Brixton,Greater London,SW2 5BZ <br>Tel: +442086710700<br/>
                <span class="type">Music Venue</span>
            </div>
                            <a href="" class="suggest-message">Suggest this date</a>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
                            <div class="suggestions">
                <header>
                    <h3>Tips</h3>
                </header>
                <ul>
                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/BX4LJ4AWOITAKFEP.png" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>Time Out London</strong> <span class="date">Mar 28, 2012</span><br />
                            The Windmill?s been revelling in its rough-around-the-edges eccentricity for years, its unprepossessing exterior a cloak for its dedication to new leftfield music.                         </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/CZ4LAAECPOPSLWFO.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>lojinx</strong> <span class="date">Nov 14, 2011</span><br />
                            Quite possibly the best music venue in London.                          </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/DSZOC3K4QKAPXSJR.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>Sonja F.</strong> <span class="date">Sep 17, 2011</span><br />
                            Voted one of the best live music venues in London                           </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/WA34MTKMKJO1KCHQ.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>Thrash Hits</strong> <span class="date">Jan 26, 2011</span><br />
                            Famous for the rock 'n' roll all-dayers with the saltiest barbecues ever. It's a(nother) good excuse to drink more beer. Great gigs happen here. Plus there is a dog on the roof. A Roof Dog.                           </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/EKEP42S0ULCMYI44.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>Drowned in Sound</strong> <span class="date">Jan 26, 2011</span><br />
                            Home of some early DiS nights and alldayers. Great little venue. Usually a free bbq on Sundays, and yeah, DOG ON THE ROOF! Like, a real Dog.                            </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/YHCPQIZ0W31MZBPM.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>Jonathan D.</strong> <span class="date">Nov 24, 2010</span><br />
                            Mind the Rottweiler on the roof! That's a bit mental!                           </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/1F3XOCML0ZKKQJOU.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>aurora</strong> <span class="date">Sep 08, 2010</span><br />
                            Looking forward to the pine hill haints gig                         </div>
                    </li>

                                        <li>
                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="https://irs1.4sqi.net/img/user/40x40/4N5O4KYF54WUYBCW.jpg" alt="user"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <strong>Jack P.</strong> <span class="date">Jul 18, 2010</span><br />
                            Quite simply Brixton's finest venue... Hook up a summer BBQ/ roofdog spotting/ awesome gig for good times...                            </div>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>  
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="refresh">
                <a href="" class="refresh-date"><img src="http://dev64238.loveflutter.com/assets/img/refresh-date.png" alt="refresh"/></a>
            </div>
                            <div class="accreditation">
                <img src="http://dev64238.loveflutter.com/assets/img/date-accreditation.png" alt="accreditation"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      initialize();
    </script>
            <div id="send-date">
        <header>
            <h3>Suggest A Date</h3>
            <a href="#" class="close-date">
                <img src="http://dev64238.loveflutter.com/assets/img/close-suggest-date.jpg" alt="close" />
            </a>
        </header>
                    <form action="http://dev64238.loveflutter.com/ajax/suggestion" name="save_suggestion" id="save_suggestion" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="4be57938bcef2d7fc3ce03e5" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="Windmill Brixton" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="phone" id="phone" value="+442086710700" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="address" id="address" value="22 Bleinheim Gdns." />
                            <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="51.45390" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" value="-0.12246" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="SW2 5BZ" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="city" id="city" value="Brixton" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="state" id="state" value="Greater London" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" value="United Kingdom" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="cc" id="cc" value="GB" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="Music Venue" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="tips" id="tips" value="8" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_to" id="user_to" value="597" />
                                <fieldset>
                    <textarea name="message" class="wysiwyg" id="messages_message">How about we meet up at Windmill Brixton, 22 Bleinheim Gdns.,Brixton,Greater London,SW2 5BZ. Sound good? <a href="http://dev64238.loveflutter.com/dating_place/541" class="suggest-date-msg">See it on map</a></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="bottom">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="username" id="messages_username" value="john_dig" type="hidden">
                    <input type="submit" class="button green rounded_5 small" value="Suggest This Date" id="senddate"/>
                    <em>or</em>
                    <a href="" id="hide-send">Back to Map</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
        </body>
```

I cannot work out why the hell, the return data is getting inserted into the `#ajax-loaded` element. Can anyone tell me why this is not working? It works perfectly in FF/Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Have you looked at the requests with Fiddler or a similar tool. Is the correct info being returned? Are there errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ajax cache false as IE has caching issues with ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Comment: Why would you turn it off for every request, that is bad advice.

Comment: Well I do only because I need to support IE.. so why manually turn it off in every ajax call.. when I can just do it for every request in one shot.

Comment: so instead of figuring out caching headers, you cause extra http requests?

Comment: @epascarello If you have a better answer, why don't you write one out?  I would actually like to find ways around this also.

Answer (score 0):

Add the callback function as the second argument, not the third one (less is more!):

```
  $(".refresh").on("click touch", function () {
      $.get($("a.suggest-date").attr('href') + '#suggestedDate', function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          $("#ajax-loaded").html(result)
      });
      return false;
  });
```